# How to bind multiple and different Controls to a ItemControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, gridview

I am new to WPF and wondering, how I could bind multiple and different **Controls** to a **ItemControl** in a **C# WPF Application**?

With my current code I can just put labels and textboxes into my ItemControl. Because of the template definition in my XAML.

But I like to be flexible to put labels and other Controls like combobox, datepicker, etc. into my ItemControl...

How could I do this?

I attached my current XAML Code with a Data Template and the code behind. And here a small picture of the current look and my target what I want:

[image]

XAML-CODE:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFFormTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="400">
<Grid>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="icFields">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="FieldTypes" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding FieldName}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

C#-Code:

```
    namespace WPFFormTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Fields> fields = new List<Fields>();
            fields.Add(new Fields() { FieldName = "test1", FieldValue = "1" });
            fields.Add(new Fields() { FieldName = "test2", FieldValue = "2" });
            fields.Add(new Fields() { FieldName = "test3", FieldValue = "3" });

            icFields.ItemsSource = fields;
        }
    }

    public class Fields
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string FieldValue { get; set; }
        public string FieldType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ItemsControl` is used for grouping. Why not to have a individual controls then placed inside grid?

Answer (score 0):

One Approach could be: add all needed controls to the template and switch the visibility. But some help from the view model is needed:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolConverter"/>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="icFields">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="FieldTypes" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding FieldName}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding ShowText, Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}"/>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding ShowCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

public class Fields
{
    public string FieldName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string FieldValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ShowText
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ShowCheckBox
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private int fieldType;

    public int FieldType
    {
        get
        {
            return fieldType;
        }

        set
        {
            fieldType = value;
            ShowText = false;
            ShowCheckBox = false;

            switch (fieldType)
            {
                case 0:
                    ShowText = true;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    ShowCheckBox = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using an [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) framework. I know that [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) has some built-in features to make this sort of thing easy, using actual OO features like polymorphism.

First you would define a separate viewmodel class for each item type:

```
public class FieldViewModel { }
public class TextViewModel : FieldViewModel { public string Value {get;set;} }
public class DateViewModel : FieldViewModel { public DateTime Value {get;set;} }
```

Then you can define a UserControl called TextView and another called DateView. When you bind your list of FieldViewModel to the UI, Caliburn.Micro will automatically create the right type of view and bind its properties.

It takes a little bit of work to get Caliburn.Micro up and running (you need to hook up the bootstrapper and create a shell viewmodel, at the very least) so I won't provide a complete code sample here -- I'm just trying to give you a flavor for whether it would solve your problem. For the actual code you need, work your way through their [documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation); they do a good job of walking you through everything.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is to just provide different `DataTemplate`s for different data types. For example, if you had a `Person` class, you could define a `DataTemplate` with `Name`, `Age`, and `Sex` `TextBox` fields, whereas if you had a `Car` class, you could define a `DataTemplate` with `Make`, `Model` and `Year` `ComboBox` fields:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:Person}">
    <!--Define TextBoxes here-->
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:Car}">
    <!--Define ComboBoxes here-->
</DataTemplate>
```

By defining these `DataTemplate`s *without specifying the `x:Key` reference values*, this means that they will be *automatically applied* by the Framework, whenever it comes across any instances of these types. Therefore, this will display `Person` details in `TextBoxes`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" ... />
```

And this will display `Car` object details in `ComboBox`es:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" ... />
```